# how i click on any links i want in watin

Tags: hyperlink, browser, watin

i use this code for find links in watin web browser

```
var lnk = browser.links.where(x => x.url.contains("example text"));
```

i accessed to founded links for click only first and last link
but i want also click on any links example click on average link.
i can get count of links with count() code and /2 for get average number of link and click on it.

so if i have 4 links i want click on second link and when i have 2 links click on 1st link

how i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want to click on the `n/2`th link?

If you make `lnk` into an indexable list, that should be pretty easy.  First make it a list:

```
var lnk = browser.Links.Where(x => x.Url.Contains("example text")).ToList();
```

Then you can reference elements by their index:

```
lnk[lnk.Count / 2].Click();
```

Conversely, you can use something like `.Skip()` in any enumeration so you don't have to incur the overhead of making it a list.  Something like this:

```
var lnk = browser.Links.Where(x => x.Url.Contains("example text"));
lnk.Skip(lnk.Count() / 2).First().Click();
```

There are [many methods available for enumerations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) which allow you to seek, transform, manipulate, and do just about anything you need to with the enumeration.